# Calculate sum filter earlier DAX PowerPivot

Tags: filter, sum, dax, powerpivot, measure

I'm trying to create a measure to calculate the sum of days absence but grouped by unique absence ID.

I have the following formula, but I keep getting an error and I just can't figure out why :/

```
Measure 1:=
CALCULATE(
  SUM('Master Absence Dates'[Approved]),
  FILTER(
    ALL('Master Absence Dates'),
    'Master Absence Dates'[Unique ID]=EARLIER('Master Absence Dates'[Unique ID],1)
  )
)
```

If anyone could shed some light on it and explain what I'm doing wrong that would be great - would love to learn how to use this formula properly! I'm wondering if i'm just attempting to use a measure like a calculated column and maybe that's just wrong in iteself!

Thank you :)

Edited to update question: So, I am looking to create the measure to sum only the values in the column 'Approved' **once** per unique value in column 'Unique ID Occurrence'. So that I get the total amount of workdays taken off - the 'Approved' column repeats the total value for the occurrence hence why i need to sum it once per unique ID :)

| Unique ID Occurrence | Approved |
| --- | --- |
| 120115-20/01/2023 | 2 |
| 121165-23/01/2023 | 4 |
| 121008-23/01/2023 | 4 |
| 121428-09/01/2023 | 50 |
| 120007-23/01/2023 | 30 |
| 121165-23/01/2023 | 4 |
| 121008-23/01/2023 | 4 |
| 121428-09/01/2023 | 50 |
| 120007-23/01/2023 | 30 |
| 148341-25/01/2023 | 3 |
| 121165-23/01/2023 | 4 |
| 120677-25/01/2023 | 1 |
| 149202-25/01/2023 | 1 |
| 121008-23/01/2023 | 4 |
| 121428-09/01/2023 | 50 |
| 120007-23/01/2023 | 30 |
| 148341-25/01/2023 | 3 |
| 121165-23/01/2023 | 4 |
| 120468-26/01/2023 | 1 |
| 150921-26/01/2023 | 2 |
| 120627-26/01/2023 | 1 |
| 121428-09/01/2023 | 50 |
| 120007-23/01/2023 | 30 |
| 148341-25/01/2023 | 3 |

Comment: What's the error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, `EARLIER` needs row context, and measures (usually) don't have it. When it comes to measures, you don't need `EARLIER` but you will need to know what you want to filter on.

Try:

```
Measure 1:=
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('Master Absence Dates'[Unique ID Occurrence]), 
    CALCULATE( MAX('Master Absence Dates'[Approved]) )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought it might be that!

It's numeric (sickness days taken). How would I go about putting it in a measure to only sum the totals where the unique id is the same? Not sure if i'm even making sense here!

I've managed to get the value i'm looking for populated in a calculated column where the total for the unique ID is repeated in each row that meets that criteria, but thought a measure may be best

Comment: Updated the answer above.

Comment: Thank you :)

So when I add it to a pivot, it still sums up all the values - take 120007-23/01/2023 for example (in above table) - it sums up as 120 for that unique ID, rather than 30 which is what i need it to show.. :/

Comment: Ah, re-read your updated question - try the answer updated above.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much that's done the job!